# My broadcast receiver is not receiving

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have used broadcast receiver with alarm manager to hit webservices for every 60 seconds,seems its working fine when i have used my broadcast receiver in different class but its not calling when i declare a receiver with in my activity

my code is below

```
public static void startAlarm(Context context) {
        Intent locationAlarm = new Intent(context, GetLocation.class);
        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();

        PendingIntent recurringAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                locationAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                updateTime.getTimeInMillis() + 500, UPDATE_INTERVAL,
                recurringAlarm);
    }
```

Broadcast receiver :

```
public class GetLocation extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            LogUtil.d("Started Service");
        }

    }
```

My Manifest file :

```
  <receiver android:name="com.sample.sample.listeners$GetLocation" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

kindly correct my mistake. my Started service method never called

Comment: If you're registering a Receiver which is an inner class of your Activity in the manifest, it needs to be a `public static class`, and its `name` attribute would be something like `".MainActivity$GetLocation"`.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks your answer make sense. let me check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your manifest file. You have put $GetLocation instead of .GetLocation

```
 <receiver android:name="com.sample.sample.listeners.GetLocation" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Even its not working. Actually my receiver class is inside of activity where i have started my alarm manager

Comment: when i use a different class its working fine.. but i need to do it in same activity

Comment: Then you need to declare your GetLocation class as a **static class** since $ is used to reference static inner classes. Also in you manifest change the name to <Path to your outer class>$GetLocation. It should work then.